# What is the difference between 'It seems like' and 'she seems'?

Tags: prepositions, difference, linking-verbs, impersonal-verb

There are two sentences.

> 1. She seems crazy.
> 2. It seems like she is crazy.

I don't know the difference between two sentences in meaning.
Could you tell me the difference in meaning between two sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, both sentences are a subjective opinion given by someone, and they have exactly the same meaning. However, the difference lies in the syntax.

> She seems crazy

is considered a *personal* sentence. This means that it is the opinion of the speaker, and the speaker doesn't shy aware from admitting it.

However,

> It seems like she is crazy

is an *impersonal* sentence (See [here](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/personal_passive.htm) for more details and examples). This means that, although it is still the speaker's opinion, they are **distancing** themselves from it, by saying "It seems that" + their opinion. They are trying to make themselves sound more objective or neutral, even when giving an opinion,
 which is always subjective.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to answer this sort of question because the nuance is almost imperceptible. There is a very slight retreat from assertion in "it seems like".

She seems crazy ~ She is acting crazy.

It seems like she is crazy ~ From her behavior, one would conclude she was crazy.

Answer (score 0):

*Like X* means:

- not actually X, but sharing some or an incomplete amount of the attributes of X
- not actually X but you could substitute X for whatever you are talking about.

X can be a word or a phrase.  *Like X* is often used as a crude hack in informal speech when the speaker (hopefully not writer) cannot immediately think of a good word and wants to "adjective-ify" a phrase for use as a subject complement.

> She seems crazy

This means from what we can see, we believe her to be crazy.

> She seems like she is crazy

This technically means "from what we can see, we believe her to be *not actually crazy but sharing some or an incomplete amount of the attributes of 'to be crazy'*".  So this is a softer way to say she's crazy without directly accusing her of being that way - or we are making a guess based on appearance, someone's description, etc.